# QListView automatic scroll on selection change with keyboard

Tags: qt, qlistview

In a QListView if you change the selection with the keyboard and it goes outside bounds (outside the viewport) the listview does not scroll to make visible the current selection. (I'd say it's the default behavior but I am not sure).

Is there a setting to automate the scrolling? (I know that with QAbstractItemView::scrollTo I can achieve that but I wonder if there's a setting to not have to intercept the change)

Comment: on my computer it scrolls automatically.

Comment: Finally I've used scrollTo(index,QAbstractItemView::EnsureVisible); After all it was not all that complicated.